# вывод двух переменных при выборе item в comobobx

Tags: c#, wpf

Как вывести переменные - Code и Name при выборе itemа в combobox1

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<States> states = new ObservableCollection<States>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            states.Add(new States() { Code = "MD", Name = "Maryland" });
            states.Add(new States() { Code = "VA", Name = "Virginia" });
            states.Add(new States() { Code = "CA", Name = "California" });
            states.Add(new States() { Code = "WA", Name = "Washington" });

            DataContext = states;
        }
    }

    public class States
    {
        public String Code
        { get; set; }

        public String Name
        { get; set; }
    }
private void Combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
        ...
        }
```

---

WPF HAML

```
<Combobox x:Name="Combobox1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Code"/>
```

Comment: Как я вам и говорил, используйте привязки. 1. Переделайте `DataContext` на `this;` (лучше отдельный класс заведите и здесь его инициализируйте). 2. Уберите `SelectionChenged`, ибо если используете привязки - он лишний. 3. Привяжите `SelectedItem` к свойству.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если знаите что нужно написать, не могли бы вы дать ответ тогда. Я не знаю как Привязать SelectedItem к свойству, И если я переделаю DataContext на this то выдает ошибку" Невозможно присвоить значение this так как он доступен только для чтения"

Comment: Я вам не буду давать ответа по двум причинам. 1. Ваш вопрос не имеет ценности для SO, то есть он проходной, который мало кому будет полезен. 2. Вы и дальше будете задавать подобные вопросы, пока сами не начнете думать, не прочитаете про привязки, как работают и что с ними можно сделать. Если я отвечу, то сниму с вас ряд задач, которые вы должны для развития решить сами, это как то не правильно... Почитайте/посмотрите что нибудь про простейшие привязки и попробуйте реализовать это сами. Будут вопросы, я всегда здесь, готов помочь, но не решать за вас..

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я прошу дополнить, я уверен для SO такой вопрос актуален так как в интернете нету что то такого. Подобные вопросы буду задавать пока не решиться данный вопрос. Вы сами себе противоречете

Comment: 1. В интернете уйма статей о том, как делать банальные привязки (вот например [первая ссылка гугла](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.1.php)). 2. Если вы увидели противоречие в моих словах, то вы меня не поняли. Я говорю, что готов вам помочь здесь, в комментариях, но не в формате Вопрос/Ответ на SO, ибо опять же, я не вижу в этом вопросе вообще не малейшего смысла, а вижу лишь то, что человек не хочет искать/обучаться.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ хорошо я сделал и это работает,  не могли бы вы проверить- правильно ли я сделал со стороны кода

Comment: Не правильно конечно. Вы убрали полностью привязки, убрали `class States`, сделали не пойми что. Я вам еще раз говорю, у вас в вопросе верный код! Вам надо всего лишь сделать `DataContext` на текущий класс, либо создать новый и добавить еще одно свойство `public States SelectedItem {get;set;}`, к которому вы привяжете `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"` у своего `Combobox`.  Событие `SelectionChanged` у вас лишнее!

Comment: @EvgeniyZ максимально сделал что сумел ниже

Comment: насчет событие SelectionChanged что заместо него использовать ?

Comment: Не хотите вы меня слушать, не хотите. Ну чтож, оформил ответ...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо большое )

Comment: @EvgeniyZ только не пойму почему мне не нужен SelectionChanged. Как я тогда буду сравнивать ?

Comment: это дело работает только в SelectionChanged if (SelectedState != null) {
                string _key = SelectedState.Code;
                string _value = SelectedState.Name;
                if (_value == "Virginia")
                {
                    textcomand.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                }
                else
                {
                    textcomand.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                }
            }

Comment: У вас в `SelectedState` будет автоматически выбранное значение, дальше делайте с ним что угодно и где угодно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ SelectedIndex="0" не работает, не выводит первое

Comment: Потому что это свойство тоже надо привязать и менять значение свойства, а не контрола. А что бы интерфейс применял обновления свойства - надо реализовать INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Тогда можно ли что бы combobox назывался например Command, а не был пустым ?

Comment: Я вам уже сказал решение. Сделайте свойство и привяжите `SelectedIndex`. Другое решение - задайте уже привязанному свойству SelectedState нужное значение из коллекции.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы много делаете лишнего и не хотите слушать от слова совсем!

Смотрите, привязка работает следующим образом:

- Задается главный источник данных, то есть `DataContext`. Из него будет идти получение всех остальных данных. Обычно создается отдельный класс, который и указывается источником данных, но в вашем случае достаточно простого `DataContext = this;`.
- Далее надо запомнить одно простое правило - "Привязки возможны только к свойствам!". И по этому нам надо сделать 2 свойства:

  1. Это коллекция класса `State` (заметьте, я поменял название вашего класса, ибо это один объект, а вы зовете его во множественном числе..). Если коллекция будет обновляться во время работы программы, то лучше использовать `ObservableCollection`, ибо она оповещает интерфейс о внутренних изменениях. Получаем следующее:

     ```
     public ObservableCollection<State> States { get; } = new ObservableCollection<State>();
     ```
  2. Далее нам нужно свойство текущего выбранного элемента. Оно будет автоматически приравниваться к выбранному элементу из `ComboBox`. Тип должен быть тем же, что и у привязанной коллекции:

     ```
     public State SelectedState { get; set; }
     ```
- Все, теперь нам осталось привязать все это в XAML разметке:

  ```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding States}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedState}" DisplayMemberPath="Code"/>
  ```

Все, теперь у вас имеется готовая привязка объектов к `ComboBox`.

Весь код будет примерно такой:

```
public class State
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<State> States { get; } = new ObservableCollection<State>();
    public State SelectedState { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        States.Add(new State() { Code = "MD", Name = "Maryland" });
        States.Add(new State() { Code = "VA", Name = "Virginia" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<States> states = new ObservableCollection<States>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.states = new ObservableCollection<States>();

            InitializeComponent();

            Combobox1.DataContext = states;

            states.Add(new States() { Code = "MD", Name = "Maryland" });
            states.Add(new States() { Code = "VA", Name = "Virginia" });

        }
        public class States
        {
            public string Code { get; set; }

            public string Name { get; set; }


        }
private void Combobox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    States states = (States)Combobox1.SelectedItem;

        string _key = states.Code;
        string _value = states.Name;
        if (_value == "Virginia") { 
            MessageBox.Show(_key);
        }
   }
```

WPF HAML

```
 <ComboBox x:Name="Combobox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" SelectedValuePath="Name"
```